# Rich text editor / RTE frameworks that works with Mark.js

Tags: wysiwyg, highlight, quill, draftjs, highlight.js

I'm working on a project where I need advanced text highlighting features on a rich text editor.

I've came across [mark.js](https://markjs.io), which has a really powerful API for text highlighting logic. However, I couldn't find any rich text editors, or rich text editor frameworks that works with mark.js.

I've been using [draft.js](https://draftjs.org/), but I recently started looking for some alternatives. There are ones that stands out, such as [Slate](https://www.slatejs.org) and [Quill](https://quilljs.com), but none of them seems to support mark.js.

Anyone know any alternative WYSIWYG editor that supports such a feature ?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: @Adders nope, ended up using Slate though.